# Force order of required TypeScript files

Tags: typescript

In my application I have splitted my classes into files:

One class for example looks like:

```
module App.Classes.Bootgrid {
    import DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings = App.Classes.JQuery.DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings;

    export class DefaultBootgridOptions implements IBootgridOptions {
        ajax = true;
        columnSelection= false;
        ajaxSettings=  new DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings();
    }
}
```

Whereas DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings.ts looks like

```
module App.Classes.JQuery {
    export class DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings implements JQueryAjaxSettings {
        async =false;
        contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        method = "GET";
        statusCode: { [index: string]: any; };
        type = "GET";
    }
}
```

At runtime I always get the the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings' of undefined

as of App.Classes.JQuery is `undefined` at point of execution. Looking at the `Network` tab in Chromes Developer tools, it shows me, that `DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings.js` file is loaded **after** the `DefaultBootgridOptions.js` which causes for sure the described error.
How can I set the order of the file to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that since jQuery 1.8 the default for jQuery $.param() serialization used by the AJAX call is traditional===false

Answer (score 0):

The order of files is controlled by the following special comments. You should add the following line to the first sample code from your question:

```
///<reference path="path/to/DefaultJQueryAjaxSettings.ts" />
```

This is how internal modules work. There are also external modules in TypeScript. Refer to http://typescriptlang.org for the differences.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the order of the file to be loaded?

Use file based modules (also called external modules) See difference : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

These kinds of errors are exactly why I recommend against `out` / `internal modules` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md